# How to update data correctly in RecyclerView to see changes after insert or update data from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am having a problem and it is that I am trying to `update` **data** from a `RecyclerView` that loads information from a `MySQL` query in `PHP`. To do this, by **clicking** on an **item** in the `RecyclerView` I open a new `Activity`, in this position the data of the `RecyclerView` item and update it. In my `DB` I see the **update**, but when I **return** to the `Activity` with the list, it **has not made** the change. I understand that for this to work i should use the `adapter.notifyItemChanged (position)`; what I don't understand is how to apply it correctly in my `Activity`. This is my `Adapter`:

```
public class RecyclerViewListaCartuchos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Cartuchos> mValues;
    Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewListaCartuchos(Context context, ArrayList<Cartuchos> values) {
        mValues = values;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.vista_diseno_cartucho, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder Vholder, int position) {
        Vholder.setData(mValues.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public CardView cardView;
        public TextView idCartucho;
        public TextView modeloColor;
        public TextView tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod;
        public ImageView iv_cartucho_img;
        public View layout;
        Cartuchos item;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            layout = v;

            v.setOnClickListener(this);
            cardView = v.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
            idCartucho = v.findViewById(R.id.idCartucho);
            modeloColor = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_modelo_color);
            tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod);
            iv_cartucho_img = v.findViewById(R.id.iv_cartucho_img);

            switch (mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
                case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
                case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
                    cardView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    idCartucho.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    modeloColor.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void setData(Cartuchos item) {
            this.item = item;
            String dato = item.getModelo() + " " + item.getColor();
            String idC = String.valueOf(item.getIdCartucho());
            String fec_us = "Última actualización: " + item.getFechaModificacion();
            idCartucho.setText(idC);
            modeloColor.setText(dato);
            tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod.setText(fec_us);

            if(item.getModelo().contains("73")){
                iv_cartucho_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.sietetresn);
            }else if(item.getModelo().contains("90")){
                iv_cartucho_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.nueveceron);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int itemPosition = getLayoutPosition();
            String idC = String.valueOf(idCartucho.getText());
            String cantidad = String.valueOf(item.getCantidad());
            //String mensaje = itemPosition + " / " + idC + "/Canti:" + cantidad;
            Intent abrirEditar = new Intent(mContext, Editar.class);
            abrirEditar.putExtra("idcartucho", String.valueOf(item.getIdCartucho()));
            abrirEditar.putExtra("cantidad", String.valueOf(item.getCantidad()));
            abrirEditar.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mContext.startActivity(abrirEditar);
            //Toast.makeText(mContext, mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

This my `activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<Cartuchos> arrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvInicio);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        listadoCartuchos();

    }

    public void listadoCartuchos() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url",
                response -> {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            int id = jsonObject1.getInt("dat");
                            String modelo = jsonObject1.getString("da");
                            String color = jsonObject1.getString("d");
                            String fec = jsonObject1.getString("data");
                            int cantidad = jsonObject1.getInt("cantidad");
                            arrayList.add(new Cartuchos(id, modelo, color, fec, cantidad));
                        }
                        RecyclerViewListaCartuchos adaptador = new RecyclerViewListaCartuchos(getApplicationContext(), arrayList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptador);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Editar Activity:

```
public class Editar extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText etEditarCantidad;
    private final String mensajeVacio = "No puede estar vacío ni el valor debe ser 0 (cero)";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editar);
        String idC = getIntent().getStringExtra("idcartucho");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(idC);
        String cantidad = getIntent().getStringExtra("cantidad");

        etEditarCantidad = findViewById(R.id.etEditarCantidad);
        etEditarCantidad.setText(cantidad);
        Button btnEditar = findViewById(R.id.btnEditar);

        btnEditar.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if(etEditarCantidad.getText().toString().length() == 0
                    || etEditarCantidad.getText().toString().equals("0")){
                Toast.makeText(Editar.this, mensajeVacio, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                try{
                    editarCantidad(id);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("Error", "Editar error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void editarCantidad(int id){
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(etEditarCantidad.getText().toString())){
            etEditarCantidad.setError("No puede estar vacío.");
            etEditarCantidad.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        String url = "url";
        final int cant = Integer.parseInt(etEditarCantidad.getText().toString());
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, response -> {
            try {
                if (response.contains("Error")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Editar.this, "Lo sentimos, ha ocurrido un error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Intent data = getIntent();
                    //put necessary data if there's any and send it back
                    setResult(1, data);
                    Toast.makeText(Editar.this, "Modificado con éxito.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Editar.this.finish();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, error -> Log.e("onErrorEdit", "onErrorResponse: " + error.getMessage())){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
                Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<>();
                parametros.put("cantidad", String.valueOf(cant));
                parametros.put("id", String.valueOf(id));
                return parametros;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Editar.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) to launch this other activity, when the other activity is closed, [onActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) in your main activity is triggered, so when that happens you know that the other activity has finished its work and you should update the item from your DB.

it goes like this :

1. main activity calls [startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) to launch the second activity with the intent that contains the data to be used in second activity and a request code which is an integer to indicate which activity you're opening (we will use later).
2. second activity does the required work provided the intent from the main activity, just before it calls finish it should call [setResult(int resultCode, Intent data)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent))
   where **result code** : an integer to indicate if the work it did resulted in success or failure (it can be any integer that you assign e.g 1 for success and 0 for failure)
   **data** : is an intent that carry some data from your second activity, for the sake of our case here just send the same intent that you received in second activity to the first one since it carries the necessary data.
3. since you started your second activity with [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)), when it gets finished, [onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) is called in main activity with the requestCode which you should use if statement on to make sure its the requestCode that you started the second activity with (where in case you have third activity that does something else you'd carry the correct operation flow when it returns), and data that should indicate which item you were doing work on.
4. since you have the required data you're free here to query your DB again to correctly update the mentioned item and then call `adapter.notifyItemChanged`.

your main activity should look like :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final int MY_SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE =2 , MY_THIRD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE =3 ;
    private final int RESULT_SUCCESS =1 , RESULT_FALIURE =0;

    ... 

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == MY_SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
            if (resultCode ==RESULT_SUCCESS)
                SecondActivityFinishedUpdateAdapterData(data);
            else somethingWrongHappenedInSecondActivity();
        }else if (requestCode == MY_THIRD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
            //do something else here in case if you have third activity
        }else  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    
    public void startMyActivity(Intent data)
    {
        startActivityForResult(data), MY_SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE );
    }
}
```

your view holder should carry a reference to your main activity to be able to call startActivityForResult (I'm not sure it's the correct way but at the moment I can't think of any other way), so it might look like this :

```
public class RecyclerViewListaCartuchos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Cartuchos> mValues;
    Context mContext;
    MainActivity myMainActivity
    public RecyclerViewListaCartuchos(MainActivity mainActivity, Context context, ArrayList<Cartuchos> values) {
        mValues = values;
        mContext = context;
        this.myMainActivity = mainActivity ;
    }
    ...
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public CardView cardView;
        public TextView idCartucho;
        public TextView modeloColor;
        public TextView tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod;
        public ImageView iv_cartucho_img;
        public View layout;
        Cartuchos item;
        MainActivity myMainActivity ;
        public ViewHolder(View v, MainActivity mainActivity) {
            super(v);
            this.myMainActivity = mainActivity ;
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int itemPosition = getLayoutPosition();
            String idC = String.valueOf(idCartucho.getText());
            String cantidad = String.valueOf(item.getCantidad());
            //String mensaje = itemPosition + " / " + idC + "/Canti:" + cantidad;
            Intent abrirEditar = new Intent(mContext, Editar.class);
            abrirEditar.putExtra("idcartucho", String.valueOf(item.getIdCartucho()));
            abrirEditar.putExtra("cantidad", String.valueOf(item.getCantidad()));
            abrirEditar.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            myMainActivity.startMyActivity(abrirEditar);

            //mContext.startActivity(abrirEditar); //commented this
            //Toast.makeText(mContext, mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

and in your second activity just before finish you should be calling setResult like this :

```
Intent data = getIntent();
//put necessary data if there's any and send it back
setResult(1,data);
finish()
```

where intent **data** should contain the necessary data to be able to update the adapter when you go back if there's any.
as an example you might use [holder.getAbsoulteAdapterPosition](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()) in your view holder onclick to get the position that was clicked and store it in the intent that will be send to be restored later to the main activity onActivityResult.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, i've a doubt, in my case i don't have an Adapter like your sample (SecondActivityFinishedUpdateAdapterData(data);) so how can i solve that?

Comment: oh no that's not an adapter, it's just an example method that you might write code for to update the adapter, it's just a name I invented to emphasize what the method might do, you're free at this point to write whatever code you like instead of this method.

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer !